# javascript with if statment to fire buttons in code behind asp.net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am adding products in gridview and a im checking if the las record exist in list i have a messege to update the existed record or delete the last inserted! Below is my code but it does not work! can anyone help me?

```
public void SaveToList()
        {
            try
            {
                OrdersDataContext contex = DataContextSingleton.Instance;

                _order = new Order();
                _order.quant = Int32.Parse(quant.Text);
                _order.price = price.Text;
                _order.totalprice = Decimal.Parse(totprice.Text);
                _order.discoun_id = Int32.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
                _order.prod_id = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
                _order.regist_id = Int32.Parse(TextBox4.Text);

                _readyToSave.Add(_order);
                //contex.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(ord);
                //contex.SubmitChanges();
                if (_readyToSave.Count() != 0)
                {
                    var selectO = (from o in _readyToSave
                                   orderby o.prod_id
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       val1 = o.prod_id
                                   }).Last();

                    TextBox15.Text = selectO.val1.ToString();

                    var selectpr = from p in _readyToSave
                                   where (p.prod_id == Int32.Parse(TextBox15.Text))
                                   select p;
                    if (selectpr.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var agree=confirm('This product exist on you order! Do you want to update it???'); if (agree){document.getElementById('<%= btnUpdate%>').click();} else{document.getElementById('<%= btnDelNew %>' ).click();}");
                        //Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('This product already have been added in list!!!')</script>");
                    }
                }

                ClearTheFields();
                Sum();
            }
            catch
            {
            }

        }
```

---

don't know why but it stops working, doesn't call button.. btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var agree=confirm('This product exists on you order! Do you want to update it???'); if (agree){document.getElementById('" + btnUpdate.ClientID + "').click();} else{document.getElementById('" + btnDelNew.ClientID + "' ).click();}"); can anyone help me???

Answer (score 1):

try with the ClientId property

```
btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var agree=confirm('This product exist on you order! Do you want to update it???'); if (agree){document.getElementById('<%= btnUpdate.ClientId%>').click();} else{document.getElementById('<%= btnDelNew.ClientId %>' ).click();}");
```

Comment: Please excuse the question: I have limited knowledge of the GridView, but will having the literal `<%=btnUpdate.ClientId%>` within the attribute of a button be automatically parsed as `ctr001_btnUpdate` (for example)?  My gut feeling is that it will simply be sent to the brower as literally just `<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>`

Answer (score 0):

You have the button names defined as `<%= btnUpdate%>` and `<%= btnDelNew %>`. They should be defined as `<%= btnUpdate.ClientID %>` and `<%= btnDelNew.ClientID  %>`.

UPDATE:
If freefaller's gut feeling is correct (I haven't tested the above), then add the `onclick` attribute as the following:

```
btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var agree=confirm('This product exist on you order! Do you want to update it???'); if (agree){document.getElementById('" + btnUpdate.ClientID + "').click();} else{document.getElementById('" + btnDelNew.ClientID + "' ).click();}");
```

Comment: Please excuse the question: I have limited knowledge of the GridView, but will having the literal `<%=btnUpdate.ClientId%>` within the attribute of a button be automatically parsed as `ctr001_btnUpdate` (for example)?  My gut feeling is that it will simply be sent to the brower as literally just `<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this without a real knowledge of GridViews, but my gut feeling is that you're literally sending the text `<%=btnUpdate%>` (or `<%=btnUpdate.ClientID%>`) to the browser.

What I think you need to do is change the line starting with...

```
btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick"...
```

To...

```
btnAdd.Attributes.Add("onclick", "var agree=confirm('This product exist on you order! Do you want to update it???'); if (agree){document.getElementById('" + btnUpdate.ClientID + "').click();} else{document.getElementById('" + btnDelNew.ClientID + "' ).click();}");
```